# How to do filtering logic based on a group by in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So let's say I have a df that looks like this:

```py
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Data1' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
                       'Data2' : [100, 100, 200, 101, 100, 100], 
                       'State' : ['On', 'On', 'Off', 'Off', 'On', 'Off'],
                       'Count' : [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                       'Total' : [25, 25, 25, 25, 150, 150]})
```

```
+-------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
| Data1 | Data2 | State | Count  | Total |
+-------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
| A     |   100 | On    |      2 |    25 |
| A     |   100 | On    |      2 |    25 |
| A     |   200 | Off   |      1 |    25 |
| A     |   101 | Off   |      1 |    25 |
| B     |   100 | On    |      1 |   150 |
| B     |   100 | Off   |      1 |   150 |
+-------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
```

How would I go about adding conditions and filter out data that I pass?

For every unique combination of Data1 and Data2 check how many 'On' states there are and if the amount of 'On' states for each unique combination is less than certain thresholds

Conditions:

- I need at least 1 'On' if Total > 0
- I need at least 2 'On' if Total > 100

So my result should look like:

```
    +-------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
    | Data1 | Data2 | State | Count  | Total |
    +-------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
    | A     |   200 | Off   |      1 |    25 |
    | A     |   101 | Off   |      1 |    25 |
    | B     |   100 | On    |      1 |   150 |
    | B     |   100 | Off   |      1 |   150 |
    +-------+-------+-------+--------+-------+
```

Things to note:

- The count column already counts how many 'on' or 'off' there is for
  each unique combination of Data1 and Data2
- Total is the same for each unique Data1

I feel like this can be done by some group by filtering? I am just not sure how to go about it. Thanks for all the help in advance.